# Fetch confusion, results in undefined object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I successfully fetch names and images for every pokemon, but when I try to fetch the forms and then the forms' respective images I get undefined objects.

**My Card.tsx component**

```
const Card = async ({ name }: Props) => {
  //Get pokemon by name
  const rawPokemon = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`);
  const pokemon = await rawPokemon.json();
  //state sprites in an array
  const sprites = [pokemon.sprites.front_default, pokemon.sprites.front_shiny];
  //Get list of forms
  const rawForms = await fetch(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form?offset=0&limit=1500`
  );
  const formsList = await rawForms.json();
  const allForms = formsList.results;
  //Filter forms by name of current pokemon
  // Returns list of objects like {
  //                                "name": "pikachu-rock-star",
  //                                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/10182/"
  //                              }
  const pFormObjects = allForms.filter((obj: any) => obj.name.includes(name));
  // for each object in pFormObjects use the url property to fetch a new object on this form:
  /*   
    {
    "form_name": "rock-star",
    "form_names": [],
    "form_order": 3,
    "id": 10182,
    "is_battle_only": false,
    "is_default": true,
    "is_mega": false,
    "name": "pikachu-rock-star",
    "names": [],
    "order": 38,
    "pokemon": {},
    "sprites": {},
    "types": [],
    "version_group": {}
    } 
    */
  const pFormImageRequests = pFormObjects.map(
    async (obj: any) => await fetch(obj.url).then((res) => res.json())
  );

  return (
    <div className="Card grid place-content-evenly text-center border-solid border-black border-2">
      <CardImage sprites={sprites} width={130} height={130}></CardImage>
      <h1 className="font-extrabold">
        {name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)}
      </h1>
      <p>{typeof pFormImageRequests}</p> {/*} returns object {*/}
      <p>{typeof pFormImageRequests[0].name}</p> {/*} returns undefined {*/}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Card;
```

**The app:**
[The app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azM4t.png)

I was expecting the `await fetch(obj.url).then((res) => res.json()` to have resolved into objects with properties like `name`, `id` and `sprites`.

Edit: when I try `<p>{pFormImageRequests[0]}</p>` I get this error.
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {form_name, form_names, form_order, id, is_battle_only, is_default, is_mega, name, names, order, pokemon, sprites, types, version_group}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Suggesting it doesnt return undefined or empty objects?

Comment: `pFormImageRequests` will be an array of *Promises* ... try `await Promise.all(......` if you want an array of actual results

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! I did `const pFormImages = await Promise.all(pFormImageRequests);` and then `pFormImages` contains the objects I desired.